How to load custom font from local path using Gtk and NodeGtk?
Have a single NodeGTK project, and try load a font file from local path using:
@font-face{
    font-display: block;
    font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
    src: url("./resources/bootstrap-icons.woff") format("woff");
}

const btnGo = builder.getObject('btn-go');
btnGo.setLabel('\uF7D1');
const context = btnGo.getStyleContext();
context.addClass('bi');

But does not work. https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-properties.html says does not support the font-face attribute. The project says unknown @ rule.
I don't want to have to install the font locally, I just want to use it within my project, but Gtk forces me to have it installed on the system through CSS rules. I also don't want to change the text font for the entire app, I just want to use the bootstrap icons in a button.
https://icons.getbootstrap.com/
